# Java 8 groupingBy cannot grouping with list paramaters

Tags: java

I encounter a problem as the title describe. Below is the code. I hope someone could help me out. Really appreciate it.

```
// this is a column class
public class Column {

    private String name;

    private Object value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

     @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj)
            return true;

        if(obj == null || obj.getClass()!= this.getClass())
            return false;

        Column column = (Column) obj;

        // comparing the state of argument with
        // the state of 'this' Object.
        return (column.name == this.name && column.value == this.value);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.value.hashCode();
    } 

}
```

```
// this is Table class
public class PhysicalTable {

    private String name;

    private List<Column> indexIdsColumns;

    private List<Column> columns;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Column> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(List<Column> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public List<Column> getIndexIdsColumns() {
        return indexIdsColumns;
    }

    public void setIndexIdsColumns(List<Column> indexIdsColumns) {
        this.indexIdsColumns = indexIdsColumns;
    }

}
```

```
// group by logic, this part is core logic.
Map<String, List<PhysicalTable>> tableMap = allTables.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PhysicalTable::getName));
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List<PhysicalTable>>> entries = tableMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, List<PhysicalTable>> entry = entries.next();
            String tableName = entry.getKey();
            List<PhysicalTable> tablesWithSameName = entry.getValue();

            //group by index ids
            Map<List<Column>, List<PhysicalTable>> map = tablesWithSameName.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PhysicalTable::getIndexIdsColumns, Collectors.toList()));
            Iterator<Map.Entry<List<Column>,List<PhysicalTable>>> iterator  = map.entrySet().iterator();
        }
```

I hope java groupingBy tables with indexIdsColumns, but it doest not work! Or java does not support that groupingBy with list paramaters？

If this grouping by solution is good, is there other way to group by the table with the index ids columns.

Thanks!

Comment: which object is this `private Object value;` representing

Comment: can yu reduce the problem to a few lines?

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Can you provide the error you see and an example of what is the output you expect?